# Modifying old GaussianProcessor example to run with GaussianProcessRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have an example from a data science book I am trying to run in a Jupyter notebook. The code sippet looks like this

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess

# define the model and draw some data
model = lambda x: x * np.sin(x)
xdata = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 8])
ydata = model(xdata)

# Compute the Gaussian process fit
gp = GaussianProcess(corr='cubic', theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1E-1,
                    random_start=100)
gp.fit(xdata[:, np.newaxis], ydata)

xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis], eval_MSE=True)
dyfit = 2 * np.sqrt(MSE)  # 2*sigma ~ 95% confidence region
```

since GaussianProcess has been deprecated and replaced with GaussianProcessRegressor. I tried to fix the code snippet to look like this

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

# define the model and draw some data
model = lambda x: x * np.sin(x)
xdata = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 8])
ydata = model(xdata)

# Compute the Gaussian process fit
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(random_state=100)
gp.fit(xdata[:, np.newaxis], ydata)

xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis])
dyfit = 2 * np.sqrt(MSE)  # 2*sigma ~ 95% confidence region
```

but I get a ValueError

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-c04ac57d1897> in <module>
     11 
     12 xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
---> 13 yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis])
     14 dyfit = 2 * np.sqrt(MSE)  # 2*sigma ~ 95% confidence region

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

bit unsure why the predict function complains here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has the answer.

At `yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis])` you are trying to assign the result of predict to two variables while the predict only returns a single `numpy.ndarray`.

To solve this issue, run

`yfit = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis])`

Comment: Ah yes I can see that. If I only run predict on yfit, how do I calculate dyfir in the next line then?

Comment: `yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis], return_std = True)`

Comment: Yes, now it works. Many thanks. The output is somewhat different but I expected that. I looked at both documentations for GaussianProcess and GaussianProcessRegressor and it is not really clear how to translate one to the other.